# How can I make forEach loop wait before it proceeds?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have a foreach loop that is, well... too fast. The device I'm trying to communicate with is confused. The device sends a response to a listener (which is somewhere else and does more than that), so it's impossible (as far as I know) to await the response somehow. So I thought I could do smt like this:

```
something.forEach(async item => {
//do smt
await setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("czekamy czekamy")
}, 2000)
})
```

hoping that it could stop the loop for executing the next iteration. But it doesn't work, obviously. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: You could make your arrow function `async`.

Comment: `forEach((item, i) => ... setTimeout(..., 2000 * i)`

Comment: isn't is possible to start the loop when the listener is triggered? in this way you wouldn't have to wait for the answer because the loop would be started after you get the answer

Comment: I'm sorry, my real life example ineed is async, I edited question.

Comment: I would have to start each iteration after there is a response to the current one but as I said it is a general listener for all responses and I really have no idea how would I do that.

Comment: You may have to go into a little more detail about the communication with your device - what data is being passed, is the communication one-way or two-way? If two-way does the next request depend on the previous response etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the forEach loop async in order to await the timeout.

```
something.forEach(async item => {
//do smt
await setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("czekamy czekamy")
}, 2000)
})
```

Edit:
You should use a Promise that resolves the timeout:

```
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function processItems() {
  await something.forEach(async item => {
    // Perform some action on each item
    console.log(item);

    // Wait for 2 seconds before processing the next item
    await delay(2000);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Promise and resolve it inside the setTimeout's callback function. Also you can't use `forEach` because it calls the callback immediately without waiting of resolving of the promise returned from the callback function:

```js
const something = [1,2];
(async()=>{
  for(const item of something){
      //do smt
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(`czekamy czekamy ${item}`);
          resolve();
      }, 2000)
      );
  }
})();
```

A more generic approach would be to create a wait promise function:

```js
const something = [1,2];
const wait = (delay = 0) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
(async()=>{
  for(const item of something){
      //do smt
      await wait(2000);
      console.log(`czekamy czekamy ${item}`);
  }
})();
```

But I would try an async generator as the final solution:

```js
const something = [1,2];

const wait = (delay = 0) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));

async function* delayQueue(iterable, delay = 0){
  for(const item of iterable){
    yield item;
    await wait(delay)
  }
}

(async()=>{
  for await(const item of delayQueue(something, 2000)){
      console.log(`czekamy czekamy ${item}`);
  }
})();
```

Also note that you can use `await` without async in the top level of JS modules:

```html
<script type="module">
const something = [1,2];

const wait = (delay = 0) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));

async function* delayQueue(iterable, delay = 0){
  for(const item of iterable){
    yield item;
    await wait(delay)
  }
}

for await(const item of delayQueue(something, 2000)){
    console.log(`czekamy czekamy ${item}`);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

`Array.forEach()` will not `await` for each item to complete.

If you want to have a serial execution so the next items waits until the previous is over, you can use a `for`-loop:

```
for (let item in something) {
  await setTimeout(...);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).